# How to define dynamically changing column number into a formula in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that calculates a formula (I know it's pretty long):

```
Cells(i, mcol) = "=IF(RC[-1]=""C"",(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4,4,0)),SUM((RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4,4,0)),(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66,C[-1],""GA + C""))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C3,3,0))))"
```

in the Vlookup it takes a 4th column in the range from `C1:C4` and the 3rd column from the range `C1:C3`.

It was ok till the column number (4 and 3) was fixed. 
Now it changes each time running For cycle.
Foe example, the second run column numbers will be 5 and 4, the third run 6 and 5 and so on till 12.
Is there any way to integrate the column number changed dynamically into the formula above?

Thanks a lot!

I put also a whole code as well.

```
Sub AutoCalcV2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, x As Integer, j As Integer, mcol As Integer
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Select
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

mcol = 71
For j = 1 To 11

    mcol = mcol + 1
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        On Error Resume Next
        Cells(i, mcol) = "=IF(RC[-1]=""C"",(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4,4,0)),SUM((RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4,4,0)),(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66,C[-1],""GA + C""))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C3,3,0))))"
Range("BT4").Select
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Which numbers in the formula are the ones you wish to make dynamic? You're entering a string into your cell, so you can manipulate it like any other string. Ex.: cell = "=A1" can become cell = "=A" & i, where the i chages and makes the range dynamic

Comment: I meant this part of formula: VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4,4,0), i would like to change 4 in a dynamic way. so the next For cycle it will become 4 +1

Comment: Change it the same way you are changing mcol in Cells(i, mcol). Keep a counter and use it as a string. GA_C!C1:C4," & str(iCounter) & ",0)

Comment: Thanks that was useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim iColumn as Integer

mcol = 71
For j = 1 To 11

    iColumn = 4
    mcol = mcol + 1

    For i = 3 To LastRow

        On Error Resume Next
        Cells(i, mcol) = "=IF(RC[-1]=""C"",(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4," & str(iColumn) & ",0)),SUM((RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4," & str(iColumn) & ",0)),(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66,C[-1],""GA + C""))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C3,3,0))))"
        Range("BT4").Select

        iColumn = iColumn + 1

    Next i
Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on what I understood, you have 3 vlookups and you want to use 4 (4+1,5+1,6+1) for first Two vlookups and 3 (3+1,4+1,5+1) for third one.

If that so, here how you can increment your 4 and 3.

```
Sub AutoCalcV2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i, n, x, j, mcol, iCol As Integer  '<-- Changed here
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Select
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    mcol = 71
    iCol = 4  '<-- Newly added
    For j = 1 To 11
        mcol = mcol + 1
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            On Error Resume Next
            'Changed the formula
            Cells(i, mcol) = "=IF(RC[-1]=""C"",(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))" & _
                "*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4," & iCol & ",0)),SUM((RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))" & _
                "*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4," & iCol & ",0)),(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66,C[-1],""GA + C""))" & _
                "*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C3," & i & ",0))))"
            Range("BT4").Select
            iCol = iCol + 1
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, it is correct and could be a solution. I just think that it is not possible to use i inside the formula, cause it takes values from 3 to LastRow. I guess it is better to define a new variable iColumn = 3

Comment: another thing that i have not noticed before is that changing iCol value running For each time, is necessary to change a range as well, so for example if iCol = 6, the range can't be C1:C4, must be C1:C6.

Comment: You can define and use new variable wherever you've to change the value every time loop runs. I just gave you the idea, you may need to change it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Take a look. I can give an suggestion for you. Not the whole formula, Just a part of `VLOOKUP`.

I know that this is your formula for cell in loop:

```
Cells(i, mcol) = "=IF(RC[-1]=""C"",(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4,4,0)),SUM((RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C4,4,0)),(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66,C[-1],""GA + C""))*(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C3,3,0))))"
```

Now is you want to change the dynamically the column according to looping. I understand the column pair as follow:

```
C1:C4 & C1:C3
C1:C5 & C1:C4
C1:C6 & C1:C5
C1:C7 & C1:C6
C1:C8 & C1:C7
C1:C9 & C1:C8
C1:C10 & C1:C9
C1:C11 & C1:C10
C1:C12 & C1:C11
```

Actually, your looping are not clear, I can't use it. So, I used as follow:

```
For column = 3 To 11

    mcol = mcol + 1

    For row = 1 To lastRow

        Cells(row , mcol) = "=IF(RC[-1]=""C"",(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*" & _
                            "(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C" & column + 1 & "," & column + 1 & ",0))" & _
                            ",SUM((RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66))*" & _
                            "(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C" & column + 1 & "," & column + 1 & ",0))" & _
                            ",(RC[-3]/SUMIFS(C[-3],C66,RC66,C[-1],""GA + C""))*" & _
                            "(VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!RC66,GA_C!C1:C" & column & "," & column & ",0))))"
    Next row

Next column
```

Try as above, it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was thinking, can't i just define one range C1:C12 and then just changing dynamically which column number to extract from Vlookup?